# How to stop upload file request in DropBox iOS Core SDK ?

Tags: ios, dropbox

I use  `[restClient uploadFileChunk:uploadId offset:offset fromPath:path];` to upload file. How to cancel upload file request ?

Answer (score 2):

***These are the methods in DropBox DBRestClient.h file has to cancel requests***

*Here the path refers to the path of the File in Dropbox*

```
- (void)cancelFileUpload:(NSString *)path; // This is for you .. 

- (void)cancelAllRequests; /* Cancels all outstanding requests. No callback for those requests will be sent */

- (void)cancelFileLoad:(NSString*)path;

- (void)cancelThumbnailLoad:(NSString*)path size:(NSString*)size;
```

Comment: does cancelFileUpload really work for you? It just does nothing for me. Did you ever face such a thing?